# vb.net, How to get the rest of a directory name, when it changes?

Tags: vb.net, directory

I have a program that writes a file to a directory and it works fine. But the directory is part of a game, and every time they update, the path changes, for ex.

```
C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\0.0.0.229\deploy\DATA\menu\hud
```

But when they update, it might change to something like:

```
C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\0.0.0.314\deploy\DATA\menu\hud
```

Note the `0.0.0.299` changed to `0.0.0.314`. I want the program to still be usable after updates. So is there anyway for it to finish the rest of the path past the `releases` folder automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a Windows Service that uses [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). It is capable of automatic detection of file/directory changes and raising event that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

dim LatestVersion as String = ..............Your Version Number....................

```
"C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\" & LatestVersion & "\deploy\DATA\menu\hud"
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all of the directories within "Releases" and find the latest version (numerical order). Then user that in your file path.

`.GetDirectories` finds all directories within a folder.